# No layers when configuring TinyOWS with MapServer

Tags: wfs, mapserver, wfs-t, tinyows

Am trying to expose a vector layer (loaded from shapefile into PostGIS) as a WFS layer using TinyOWS.

Following the instructions in the mapserver/tinyows documentation, here is the .map file I have come up with so far:

```
MAP
    NAME "world"
    CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/home/balajeerc/Projects/Build_Dir/myproject/data/logs/mapservice_errors.log"
    EXTENT -180.000 -90.000 180.000 90.000

    WEB    
        METADATA
            "tinyows_schema_dir" "/home/balajeerc/Projects/Build_Dir/myproject/deps/mygis-services-0.1/data/schema"
            "tinyows_onlineresource" "http://192.168.43.164:19090/vectors/world/wfs?"
            "wfs_title" "MyGIS Feature Service: World"
            "wfs_contact" "support@giscompany.com"
            "wms_title" "MyGIS Feature Service: World"
            "wms_srs" "epsg:4326"
            "wms_enable_request" "*"
            "log_level" "15"
            "log" "/home/balajeerc/Projects/Build_Dir/myproject/deps/mygis-services-0.1/data/logs/wfs_world.log"
            "ows_contactorganization" "GeorbisServer"
            "ows_contactelectronicmailaddress" "contact@giscompany.com"
            "ows_contactperson" "Balajee.R.C"
        END
    END

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END

    LAYER
        NAME 'world_boundaries'
        CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
        CONNECTION "host=localhost user=mygis password=asdf123 dbname=mygis port=19095"
        DATA "geom from world_boundaries"
        TYPE POLYGON
        METADATA
            'wfs_title' 'world_boundaries'
            'wfs_namespace_prefix' 'tows'
            'wfs_namespace_uri' 'http://www.giscompany.com/'
            'wfs_srs' 'epsg:4326'
            'wms_srs' 'epsg:4326'
            'wms_title' 'world_boundaries'
            'tinyows_table'  'world_boundaries'
            'tinyows_writable' '1'
            'tinyows_retrievable' '1'
        END
        CLASS
            STYLE
                COLOR 128 128 128
                ANTIALIAS true
            END
        END
        PROJECTION
          "init=epsg:4326"
        END
        DUMP TRUE
    END
END
```

This .map file works fine with MapServer, i.e. I am able to render the feature layer as a WMS service using QGIS as a client.

However, the WFS service (served by tinyows) using the same file (set using `TINYOWS_MAPFILE` environment variable seems to show no layers in GetCapabilities (and hence QGIS is not able to load any).

The output from `tinyows --check` is as follows:

```
balajeerc@Balajee:~/Projects/tinyows-1.1.1$ ./tinyows --check
TinyOWS version:   1.1.0
FCGI support:      Yes
Config File Path:  /home/balajeerc/Projects/Build_Dir/myproject/data/service_data/data/wfs/world.map (Mapfile)
PostGIS Version:   2.1.8
PostGIS dsn:       host=localhost user=mygis password=asdf123 dbname=mygis port=19095
Output Encoding:   UTF-8
Database Encoding: UTF8
Schema dir:        /home/balajeerc/Projects/Build_Dir/myproject/deps/mygis-services-0.1/data/schema
Display bbox:      Yes
Estimated extent:  No
Check schema:      Yes
Check valid geoms: Yes
Available layers:
balajeerc@Balajee:~/Projects/tinyows-1.1.1$
```

Note that even though I am using a 1.1.1 version of TinyOWS, it prints TinyOWS version as 1.1.0. Also note that it prints no layers.

Wondering what is going wrong, I decided to step into the code. I recompiled code after turning off (`-O2`) optimizations and with debugging (`-g`) enabled.

I am only able to get so far as the `ows_parse_config` method in `src/ows/ows_config.c`. I am, for some reason not able to step into `ows_parse_config_map` in `src/mapfile/mapfile.c`. This probably has something to do with the fact that `mapfile.c` is generated by flex using `src/map/mapfile.l`.

At this point I am completely stuck and at a brick wall as to what might be going wrong. Can someone here please help?

Comment: I made a test on Windows with MS4W and I do not believe that TINYOWS_MAPFILE is honored. If I set it tinyows is still reading the tinyows.xml file. It feels like such a but that only MapServer developer can help. Some of those follow the mapserver-users list.

Comment: @user30184 I have posted there too.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have WMS enabled with this statement:

`"wms_enable_request" "*"`

But where is the comparable statement for WFS?

`"wfs_enable_request" "*"`

This probably has an influence on your WFS not working